# Openshift to fix error Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, flask, openshift, wsgi

I have flask wsgi application but it is not working because of MySQLdb connection error.

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

How I can fix it on OPENSHIFT?
I can connect through >>mysql or in ipython with MySQLdb.connect

Comment: Have you deployed MySQL backend onto OpenShift?

Comment: Yes. I resolve this issue. Each time when i change code i need to restart app. So I added port 3306 to connection, then restart app and all work perfect.